# Python URL splitting

Tags: python, string, url, tld

I have a string like `google.com` in Python, which I would like split into two parts: `google` and `.com`. The problem is where I have a URL such as `subdomain.google.com`, which I would like to be split into `subdomain.google` and `.com`.

How do I separate the rest of the URL from the TLD? It can't operate based on the last `.` in the URL because of TLDs such as `.co.uk`. Note the URL does not contain http:// or www.

Comment: This is becoming a much more fun problem with the imminent new gTLDs. Soon we'll be separating 'search.google' too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[tldextract](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tldextract) looks like what you need. It deals with the `.co.uk` issue.

Answer (score 1):

I used [tdl](https://pypi.org/project/tld/) and [urllib](https://pypi.org/project/urllib5/), but did not find them satisfying.
I found this question multiple times on my Google search on how to parse a URL.
After a while, I took the time to make a regex and make it into an open source package.

It handles URLs which have a secondary top-domain like co.uk, and also supports national URLs with special characters.

[url-parser on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/url-parser)
[URL Parser on GitHub](https://github.com/AdaptedAS/url_parser)

For you, it would be easy to use it like this:

Step one:

```
pip install url-parser
```

Step two:

```py
from url_parser import parse_url


url = parse_url('subdomain.google.com')
url['subdomain'] # subdomain
url['domain'] # google
url['top_domain'] #com
```

You can use these keys to get the different part of the URL.

- `protocol`
- `www`
- `sub_domain`
- `domain`
- `top_domain`
- `dir`
- `file`
- `fragment`
- `query`

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need a list of valid domain names.  The top level ones (.com, .org, etc.) and the country codes (.us, .fr, etc.) are easy to find.  Try http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registries/tlds.

For the second level ones (.co.uk, .org.au) you might need to look up each country code to see its sub domains.  Wikipedia is your friend.

Once you have the list, grab the last two parts from the name you have (google.com or co.uk) and see if it is in your second level list.  If not, grab the last part and see if it is in your top level list.